# Error "Row given with size different than 2" when using Google Visualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I have a template that uses jQuery/AJAX to pull some data. Getting the data isn't an issue, but I can't seem to use it in a way that GoogleVis wants. The line causing problems for me is `mapdata.addRows([gapidata]);`. It seems there's an issue with the array but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

The jQuery/AJAX I'm using:

```
        var gapidata = new Array();
        $.ajax({
          url: "inc/index.gapi.inc.php",
          cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
          success: function(html){
            gapidata = html;
          }
        });
```

The data I get from the AJAX call:

```
    ['Korea, Republic of', 50],['Japan', 38]
```

The code I use to display the data:

```
        // Geo Map Chart
        var mapWidth = Math.round(((screenWidth / 12) * 10) * 0.8);
        var mapHeight = Math.round(mapWidth * 0.5);

        $('#dashboard-visit-map').width(mapWidth*1.1);
        $('#dashboard-visit-map').height(mapHeight*1.1);
        var mapdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        mapdata.addColumn('string','Country');
        mapdata.addColumn('number','IPs Listed');
        mapdata.addRows([gapidata]);

        var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('dashboard-visit-map'));
        geochart.draw(mapdata, {width: mapWidth, height: mapHeight,backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' }});
```

Currently the map doesn't populate with any data. If I remove the brackets around `gapidata` I receive the following error on my JavaScript console:

```
    Uncaught Error: Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table).
```

Comment: If you are using `data.addRows()`, are you being sure to add headers before the rows with `data.addColumn('type', 'label')`? You should have 2 columns for country and data at least...

Comment: That's what these are doing (I think!)

        mapdata.addColumn('string','Country');
        mapdata.addColumn('number','IPs Listed');

Comment: Ah, quite correct. So it looks like your data isn't being formatted correctly for some reason. Are you absolutely sure the object is only in the format you said it is (`['Korea, Republic of', 50],['Japan', 38]`)?

Comment: I truncated the data in my post because there are too many entries to post on here, but that's a snippet of the output I get when I run the script that generates it. The AJAX call is also working as I'm able to display that data on the page itself. I've pastebined it here to avoid rage: [link](http://pastebin.com/0cJcidk5) Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

I just normalized my data frame before calling the rendering function; it worked fine for me.

Normalizes data frame:

```
data <- as.data.frame.matrix(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

the solution is.

re-initialize  your chat visulization object mapdata for each ajax request;

i.e.
//        before calling ajax

```
    mapdata = null;
    mapdata = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

//        ajax code`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer may not be related to your code format, but it may help other people, as it is for the same issue. If you make an AJAX call to json data and then you loop over them, then you must be sure that you include all the columns of the JSON data in the addCollumn() method. If you don't want to include all of the data, then you should use the `delete` command in the for-loop like this:

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('string','category');
dataTable.addColumn('string','context');
dataTable.addColumn('string','id');
dataTable.addColumn('number','location_subtype');
dataTable.addColumn('string','location_type');
dataTable.addColumn('string','month');
dataTable.addColumn('string','persistent_id');
var json=JSON.parse(jsonData);
for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
  //Deleted rows
  delete json[i].location;
  delete json[i].outcome_status;
  var row = [];        
  for (var item in json[i]) {
    row.push(json[i][item]);
  }        
  dataTable.addRow(row);
}
```

If you don't delete them, then it is assumed that you need those data and the table takes an unexpected size by default. Therefore, you will encounter the error in the console. I hope that this may be helpful for some people. Cheers